# Lazy JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript

Problem --

users use a library, to send logs to the backend. The library has a circular buffer, so that there are no more then a few hundred elements.

However, we don't control the size of the elements that are sent, so it's possible to have payloads > 10mb.

I'd like to reduce this, by asserting a limit on the overall size of the payload.

However, I don't think there is a way for me to get the `size` of objects.

What I'm thinking is a sort of lazy JSON.stringify

```
var res = "[";
messages.forEach(m => {
  if (res.length < MAX_SIZE) {
    res += JSON.stringify(m);
    res += ",";
  })
});
res += "]"
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Isn't doing `if (JSON.stringify(obj).length > arbitraryLimit) throw new Error("too large payload");` simple enough? You don't need to truncate the JSON, do you? And if you do, how much do you care about efficiency?

Comment: you could use  some/every instead of forEach to stop early instead of continuing iteration and failing the conditional each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, it would have been simpler to do this kind of filtering *before* the JSON.stringify call.

i.e: go over `messages`, replace items that are too large with `"..too large.."`, and then stringify.